# WORD VBA add items to userform listbox from excel file

Tags: vba, ms-word

How can I load items into word userform1 listbox1
from excel file located in desktop file name book1 sheet1 table1 (4 columns A-D)

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and consider expanding your question with more information.

Comment: You seem to be making a habit of cross-posting without links. Cross-posted at: https://www.excelforum.com/word-programming-vba-macros/1373783-load-data-from-excel-table-to-word-userform-listbox.html#post5650238. For cross-posting etiquette, please read: http://www.excelguru.ca/content.php?184

Answer (score 0):

```vb
MyListBox.List = Application.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\" & environ("Username") & "\Desktop\Book1.xlsx").Worksheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("Table1").DataBodyRange.Columns(1).Resize(,4).Value
```